# subtract current column value from the previous column of the same row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to subtract the current column value from the previous column value of the same row (axis=1) except the first column value

```
My Dataframe:

   A   B  C  D
0  5  11  4  5
1  3   2  3  4
2  6   4  8  2
3  4   3  5  8

Expected Dataframe:

   A   B  C  D
0  5   6 -2  7
1  3  -1  4  0
2  6  -2  10 12
3  4  -1  6  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no build-in function for cum-diff

```
for x, y  in enumerate(df.columns):
    if x ==0 : 
        df[y]=df[y]
    else : 
        df[y]=df[y]-df[df.columns[x-1]]

df
Out[494]: 
   A  B   C  D
0  5  6  -2  7
1  3 -1   4  0
2  6 -2  10 -8
3  4 -1   6  2
```

---

```
def cumdiff(df,axis):
    if axis==1 :
        for x, y in enumerate(df.columns):
            if x == 0:
                df[y] = df[y]
            else:
                df[y] = df[y] - df[df.columns[x - 1]]
        return df
    else : 
        for x, y in enumerate(df.index):
            if x == 0:
                df[y] = df[y]
            else:
                df[y] = df[y] - df[df.columns[x - 1]]
        return df

cumdiff(df,axis=1)
Out[501]: 
   A  B   C  D
0  5  6  -2  7
1  3 -1   4  0
2  6 -2  10 -8
3  4 -1   6  2
```

Comment: Hey, I want the result exactly opposite of cumulative sum..I want the subtraction. I need to subtract the previous value(updated one not the original one) from the current col value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just using [pandas.DataFrame.expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) and [reduce function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/). So your code can looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data =  [[5,  11,  4,  5],
         [3,   2,  3,  4],
         [6,   4,  8,  2],
         [4,   3,  5,  8]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A','B','C','D'])

print(df)
>>>   A   B  C  D
   0  5  11  4  5
   1  3   2  3  4
   2  6   4  8  2
   3  4   3  5  8

diff_df = df.expanding(axis=1).apply(lambda x: reduce(lambda a,b : b-a,x)).astype(int)

print(diff_df)
>>>   A  B   C  D
   0  5  6  -2  7
   1  3 -1   4  0
   2  6 -2  10 -8
   3  4 -1   6  2
```